# java/beginner. trying to understand what i'm doing wrong with this one

Tags: java

im new to java and just trying to get this little game to work with these rules:
basically you type 2 words and it says are chars correct/present/absent comparing 2 words.
I'd be happy to analyze your ways to code this. thanks!

- s[1]=q[1] -> correct
- s[1]!=q[1] but this character is present (for    example s[4]=q[1])
  -> present
- s[1]!=q[1] and there's no present    letters -> absent

So the question is how to properly create a cycle that uses  `char[] qArray` and checks if it has same letters with `String isUsed` and `String s` ? i tried different methods and now im getting `incompatible types: char cannot be converted to java.lang.CharSequence` error

```
 import java.io.*;
 import java.lang.String;
 import java.lang.Character;
 public class Quiz {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String s = new String(br.readLine());
        String q = new String(br.readLine());
        s = s.toUpperCase();
        q = q.toUpperCase();

        char[] sArray = s.toCharArray();//s - word which you need to guess
        char[] qArray = q.toCharArray();//q - trying to guess with this word
        String isUsed = new String(""); //letters which are already in use

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if (qArray[i] == sArray[i]) {                    // if correct
                System.out.println("CORRECT "+qArray[i]);
                isUsed = isUsed + Character.toString(sArray[i]);
               // System.out.println(s);
            }
            else{                                          //!=correct&!=isUsed
                if((s.contains(qArray[i])) && (qArray[i] != isUsed.contains(i))){//how do you 
                                                                                       do this correctly?
                    System.out.println("PRESENT " +qArray[i]);
                    isUsed = isUsed + Character.toString(i);
                }
                else {System.out.println("ABSENT");}

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What's your question? StackOverflow is a place to get help. If you're looking for a peer review, you can head over to the [Code Review StackExchange site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). If you're having an issue, include a description of the issue you're encountering along with what you've  tried, what happened, and how it's different than what you expect. https://idownvotedbecau.se/unclearquestion

Comment: @Jesse thank you for feedback. i edited post and clarified my question

Comment: I fixed the formatting of your code. In the future, format a code sample by *either* indenting with four SPACE characters, *or* wrapping in a pair of triple backpacks — but not a mix of both.

Comment: Don't do `new String(br.readLine())`, doing `br.readLine()` is sufficient, same goes for `new String("")`, using `""` is sufficient.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So, if I got it right, you have 2 inputs , the wordToBeGuessed and the guessWord, right?

So, for the first part that you want to compare characters in the same position, you got it right :

```
...
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if (qArray[i] == sArray[i]) {                    // if correct
                System.out.println("CORRECT "+qArray[i]);
                isUsed = isUsed + Character.toString(sArray[i]);
               // System.out.println(s);
            }
...
```

As far as it goes for the else case, you will need another loop so you can compare if the character in **i** position of the first word, can be found in any (**j**) position on the second word.

```
for (int i = 0; i < firstWord.length; i++) {
   for(int j = 0; j < secondWord.length; j++){
      if(firstWordArray[i] == secondWordArray[j]){
         System.out.println("Letter \"" + firstWordArray[i] + "\" was found in the wrong position: " + i + ". The correct position is: " + j);
         break;
      }
   }
}
```

Eventually, I hope this is what you're looking for:

```
 import java.io.*;
 import java.lang.String;
 import java.lang.Character;

 public class Quiz {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.print("Please type word: ");
        String word = new String(br.readLine()).toUpperCase();
        System.out.print("Please type guess word: ");
        String wordToGuess = new String(br.readLine()).toUpperCase();
        
        char[] wordToGuessArray = wordToGuess.toCharArray();//s - word which you need to guess
        char[] wordArray = word.toCharArray();//q - trying to guess with this word
        
        String isUsed = ""; //letters which are already in use

        if(wordToGuessArray.length >= wordArray.length){
            for (int i = 0; i < wordArray.length; i++) {
            if (wordArray[i] == wordToGuessArray[i]) {                    // if correct
                System.out.println("The letter \" " + wordArray[i] + " \" in correct position: " +i);
            }
            else{                                          
                boolean foundFlag = false;
                for(int j = 0; j < wordToGuessArray.length; j++){
                    if(wordArray[i] == wordToGuessArray[j]){
                        isUsed = isUsed + wordArray[i];
                        System.out.println("Letter \"" + wordArray[i] + "\" was found in the wrong position: " + i + ". The correct position is: " + j);
                        foundFlag = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(!foundFlag){
                    System.out.println("Letter \"" + wordArray[i] + "\" (position:"+ i +") was not found in the word you need to guess");
                }
                

            }
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Second word needs to have more or equal letters.");
    }
        
  }
}
```

**Please make sure to use meaningful names for your variables, methods etc.**

Comment: **Please fully explain your answer with separate non-code paragraphs of text**. Code-dump answers are completely unhelpful to future visitors which is the entire purpose of this site.

Comment: @a_glampedakis `  isUsed = isUsed + Character.toString(i);` how do you do this? i tried different methods, looked up information that you can't change length

Comment: @acar , isUsed is a String. You can concatenate strings very easily in java, basically you can just add a string with a character just like "asb"+'c'. You can change the length of a string. What you can't change is the size of an Array. You can although create a new one.

Comment: thank you for explanation, i'm amazed how you got it right and clean. `Eventually, I hope this is what you're looking for:` gives a lot of answers thanks